# Placing Django Locale outside of project folder

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I have a slight problem that I need assistance/ thoughts on how to solve.

I have a question regarding generating *.po files for locale translations in django. I use a Fabric script to deploy a brand new folder with every release of code but have moved the **locale** folder outside the project since I want that to be the same for every new release and update it locally.

However, when I am trying to run `python manage.py makemessages -l en` django complains about me not having any locale folder where I am running the command.

```
CommandError: This script should be run from the Django Git tree or your 
project or app tree. If you did indeed run it from the Git checkout or 
your project or application, maybe you are just missing the conf/locale 
(in the django tree) or locale (for project and application) directory? 
It is not created automatically, you have to create it by hand if you 
want to enable i18n for your project or application.
```

I did supply a locale-path to the location outside of the project in the settings and that works fine when django is reading the files. However, it seems like it needs one in the working path for generating the strings to translate as well.

I have solved it now by making a soft link (`ln -s`) pointing at the `locale` folder outside the project in the working folder but then my language handler, rosetta, thinks I have two different apps that needs to be translated. They are the same though and if I change one the other is changed as well, but it feels funky... Any idea on how to solve it in a better/ more pythonic way?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the source for the makemessage command:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py#L256

It seems that it only takes the `LOCALE_PATHS` setting into account if you don't have a folder called `conf/locale`. See if you have the `conf/locale` folder and remove it if you do. Also tracing through that code can perhaps help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, theres no conf/locale folder(s) but I´ll plow through the code and see if I can find something.

Comment: Seems like the code you are referring to is newly added to django core, tagged 1.7b. That is quite unlucky! Well, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I´ll solve it with the soft link for the time being. Discovered that one only need the link to generate the dynamic tags, once that is done its seems fine to remove it.